# Sorting array of dictionaries with Any value

Tags: swift

I have this `[[String:Any]]`, where Every element have this:

```
["date":Date,"value":CGFloat]
```

I would like to sort by "date" key.(dates goes up or down)

```
 let sortedArray = array.sort { ($0["date"] as? Date) < ($1["date"] as? Date) }
```

Provides errors that I can't compare 2 dates.

Comment: Convert the values to structs first and stop using `Any`.

Comment: You are encouraged to use a custom struct, it makes life much easier. And with this syntax you have to use `sorted {...`

Comment: It is always a good idea to show the exact error messages ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort` is mutating so array need to be `var` and no return ,  and either force unwrap or

```
array.sort { ($0["date"] as! Date  ) < ($1["date"] as! Date   ) }
```

or

```
array.sort { ($0["date"] as? Date ?? Date()  ) < ($1["date"] as? Date ?? Date() ) }
```

---

or `sorted`

```
let sortedArray  =   array.sorted { ($0["date"] as? Date ?? Date()  ) < ($1["date"] as? Date ?? Date() ) }
```

---

Strongly recommend

```
struct Root { 
  let date:Date 
  let value:CGFloat 
}     


var array = [Root(date: Date(), value: 12),Root(date: Date(), value: 14),Root(date: Date(), value: 15)]

 let sortedArray =   array.sorted {  $0.date < $1.date }

// or

let sortedArray = array.sorted {  $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending }
```

Comment: Thanks , for the first example I get a warning : Variable 'sortedArray' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected

Comment: I know Struct is better, but changing to it will require changing the whole code.

Comment: The current date (`Date()`) as default value could cause funny unexpected behavior particularly both values of `Date()` could be different. 

Comment: Thanks. Can you show please how would you answer this if it was array of Struct ?

Comment: *will require changing the whole code*. @Curnelious Do it. It's worth it.

Comment: @vadian i agree  he op should make sure no value is nil and use **!**

Comment: Thanks all! Will do :)

Comment: @Sh_Khan For a fixed date far far away there is `distantPast` and `distantFuture`.

Comment: @vadian i provided the other alternative as you know guys here don't like **!** even if all values are not nil

Comment: Thanks, btw, using structure has its own problems, yea more elegant, but the whole project turns to be completely dependent, every class now need to know this structure, unlike a dic.

Comment: @Curnelious always think in writing clean code even if you'll be under a pressure

Comment: @Sh_Khan so ? making the whole project depend on a Struct is not that clean ?:) think about it, now every class in the system that needs this data, must know about this structure.. anyway I listen to you and changed it to struct /